# Multiplying values by a set variable across 181 text files using python

Tags: python

I hope this question follows the rules of the site. So I many text files with hundreds of values each for example:

```
#under the rule of Russia in 1836
#Erivan (128000/32000 POPS)
1098 = {
    bureaucrats = {
        culture = russian
        religion = orthodox
        size = 50
    }
    clergymen = {
        culture = russian
        religion = orthodox
        size = 10
    }
    soldiers = {
        culture = russian
        religion = orthodox
        size = 75
    }
    aristocrats = {
        culture = armenian
        religion = coptic
        size = 175
    }
    bureaucrats = {
        culture = armenian
        religion = coptic
        size = 25
    }
    officers = {
        culture = armenian
        religion = coptic
        size = 50
    }
    clergymen = {
        culture = armenian
        religion = coptic
        size = 125
    }
    soldiers = {
        culture = armenian
        religion = coptic
        size = 125
    }
    farmers = {
        culture = armenian
        religion = coptic
        size = 11850
    }
    
    farmers = {
        culture = sephardic
        religion = jewish
        size = 200
    }
    aristocrats = {
        culture = azerbaijani
        religion = sunni
        size = 200
    }
    clergymen = {
        culture = azerbaijani
        religion = sunni
        size = 100
    }
    artisans = {
        culture = azerbaijani
        religion = sunni
        size = 550
    }
    soldiers = {
        culture = azerbaijani
        religion = sunni
        size = 100
    }
    farmers = {
        culture = azerbaijani
        religion = sunni
        size = 10050
    }
    aristocrats = {
        culture = kurdish
        religion = sunni
        size = 25
    }
    clergymen = {
        culture = kurdish
        religion = sunni
        size = 25
    }
    farmers = {
        culture = kurdish
        religion = sunni
        size = 1850
    }
    
    farmers = {
        culture = kurdish
        religion = yazidi
        size = 1000
    }
    
    farmers = {
        culture = assyrian
        religion = catholic
        size = 300
    }
}
```

I am only trying to multiply numbers that come after "size = " for example for for the variable 2 `size = 100` would become `size = 200` of course
I had a more code savvy friend make a Python script similar to what I am looking for but it did not work for this so today I am trying to learn Python in order to understand how to do it on my own so this is what code I got so far:

```
import operator
import glob
import os
file_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "FolderName", "*.txt"))

factor = 1.25
count = 0

for index, line in enumerate(data):
    try:
        first_word = line.split()[0]
    except IndexError:
        pass

    if first_word == 'size':
        split_line = line.split(' ')
        # print(' '.join(split_line))
        # print(split_line)
        new_line = split_line

        new_line[-1] = ("{0:.6f}".format(float(split_line[-1]) * factor))
        new_line = ' '.join(new_line) + '\n'
        # print(new_line)

        data[index] = new_line

        count += 1

    elif first_word == 'text_scale':
        split_line = line.split(' ')
        # print(split_line)
        # print(' '.join(split_line))
        new_line = split_line

        new_line[-1] = "{0:.2f}".format(float(split_line[-1]) * factor)
        new_line = ' '.join(new_line) + '\n'
        # print(new_line)

        data[index] = new_line

        count += 1


os.chdir("/mydir")
for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    print(file)

print("Lines changed:", count)
```

Sorry if this has been answered before or if I need more experience.

Comment: "today I am trying to learn Java" - sir, this is Python. Also, what's your question and what's the problem with this code? BTW, in `for index, line in enumerate(data)` the name `data` doesn't exist, so it's not clear what you're iterating over.

Comment: sorry that was a typo, I am trying to edit the code in order find line with "size" and multiply it by a set variable say 0.5 within the text file and thank you, for you data part